# sympy - manipulate expressions containing commutator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computer-algebra-systems

Let's consider this simple example: a particle in a one-dimensional parabolic potential. In the following, $p$ is the particle momentum operator, $m$ is the mass, $x$ is the position operator, and $\omega$ is related to the potential depth.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left[x, p \right] &= xp - px = i \hbar \\
H &= \frac{p^{2}}{2 m} + \frac{1}{2}m \omega^{2} x^{2} \\
a &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 m \hbar \omega}} (m \omega x + i p)
\end{aligned}
$$
$H$ is the Hamiltonian and $a$ is the creation operator.

Let say I would like to evaluate $\left[ H, a \right]$.

`from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.quantum import Commutator, Dagger, Operator
m, omega, h = symbols("m, \omega, \hbar", real=True)
x = Operator('x')
p = Operator('p')
H = (p**2 / m + m * omega**2 * x**2) / 2
a = 1 / sqrt(2 * m * h * omega) * (m * omega * x + I * p)
comm = Commutator(H, a)
simplify(expand(comm.doit()))`

This snippet of code will produce:

$$
\frac{\sqrt{2} \omega \left(- i \omega m p x^{2} + i \omega m x^{2} p + p^{2} x - x p^{2}\right)}{4 \sqrt{\hbar \omega m}}
$$

At this point, I would like to make sympy aware of the fact that $\left[x, p \right] = xp - px = i \hbar$, and then simplifying it further to achieve the final result ($\left[ H, a \right] = -\frac{\hbar \omega}{2} a$). How can I do it?